# Why does execve sometimes set errno and not print the error message?

Tags: c, process, exec, execve

Yes, I have read the homework policy [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Notice here how, for `ls ls` it prints the error message but, for `cd test` (test does not exist), it sets the errno to 2 (no such file or directory) but does not print the error message. Why is there this difference in behavior?

I am trying to implement a simple shell using child processes. My operating system is Ubuntu Desktop 22lts. `execve` seems to sometimes allow the program to print its error message but other times will just set an errno.

Here is the code which runs in the child process.

```
            int val;
            if(strcmp(tokens[0], "cd") == 0){
                val = execve("/bin/cd", tokens, NULL);

            }
            if(strcmp(tokens[0], "ls") == 0){
                val = execve("/bin/ls", tokens , NULL);

            }
            if(strcmp(tokens[0], "cat") == 0){
                val = execve("/bin/cat", tokens, NULL);

            }
            if(strcmp(tokens[0], "echo") == 0){
                val = execve("/bin/echo", tokens, NULL);

            }
            if(strcmp(tokens[0], "sleep") == 0){
                val = execve("/bin/sleep", tokens, NULL);

            }
            if(strcmp(tokens[0], "date") == 0){
                val = execve("/bin/date", tokens, NULL);

            }
            if(strcmp(tokens[0], "pwd") == 0){
                val = execve("/bin/pwd", tokens, NULL);

            }
            if(val == -1){
                int err = errno;
                printf("%d", errno);
                printf("Incorrect command.\n");
            }
```

Here is the output[image]

Comment: Your code only prints `errno` if `execve()` itself fails, which it will for `cd` because there's no command by that name (it's a shell builtin, not a freestanding program)

Comment: Before you go and fire off `execve` calls you may want to check that path exists. To add on what Shawn said, anything that alters the state of the shell is a built-in and cannot be invoked this way. In C there is `chdir()` for situations like that.

Comment: @tadman Calling execve on a path *is* how you check if it exists. Any other procedure has a TOCTOU race.

Comment: @zwol Oh, for sure, but I mean a trivial `ls /bin/cd` could have revealed a *lot* here.

Answer (score 3):

> `execve` seems to sometimes allow the program to print its error message but other times will just set an errno.

`execve()` does not particularly constrain the behavior of the programs it starts.  After all, it is involved in starting almost every program that *ever* starts.

What you're seeing is a difference between `execve()` itself failing on one hand, and `execve()` succeeding, but the resulting program failing on the other.  If `execve()` succeeds in loading and starting a new program image then its job is done.  It does not return, in part because there is nothing left to return *to*.  The new image has replaced the one in which `execve()` was called.  Any error reporting that is performed will be performed by the new process, which is what you see for `ls ls`.

Only if `execve()` fails does it return.  This is most often because the first argument does not identify an existing file that `execve()` is capable of launching.  When it fails, yes, it sets `errno`.  This is what you observe in the `cd` case -- not because `test` does not exist, but because `/bin/cd` does not.

By the way, you might want to look into `perror()`.  It will print a more informative message than the raw `errno` value.